# Simulation of Aloha Pure

Tags: javascript, network-programming, protocols, simulation, network-protocols

**Hi!**

I’m trying to create an Aloha Pure simulation but it doesn’t seem to work correctly.

I have 10.000 stations that send packets. Each packet has a lenght of 10 bit and the channel's speed is 1 bit/sec. What is the probability that each station has to send a packet in a second? 
I'm looking for the probability needed to reach teorical limit of 18.4%.

Actually my code has:

```
N = 10.000 -> (stations number)

DimPacket = 10

t = 1 -> (channel's speed, each sec the stations try to send packets with probability p)

p = 1/(2*N*DimPacket/t) -> probability that each sec a station has to send a packet
```

According to Aloha Pure analysis [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet#Pure_ALOHA ] I’ve a probability of 1/2N but the stations try to send 10 times in a DimPacket (denoted as T on Wikipedia) then i divided the probability to DimPacket/t. But it doesn't work.

The complete code: https://github.com/Luca4k4/alohaPure

Any ideas?

Thank you!